# Two sets of resources for one application

Tags: android, branding

I'm developing an android application for a company that requires two different brandings for different client. I'm coding with Eclipse, and I'd like to know if it is possible to configure it to compile the application with each **res** folder, hence giving 2 differents .apk files.

Thanks,
Antoine

Comment: it's the right time to branch your project in your VCS

Comment: That's what I am about to do. Branching to company's SVN, with compilation scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). You can have the code of the app and default resources  in a library project, referenced from two (or more) app projects. In each app project you can override the resources as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In 1 project you can have multiple drawables, or layout folders. But they correspond to different properties about the device you are running on.(layout-land, drawable-hdpi-large etc) I don't think that is going to work for what you are trying to do though. To my knowledge you are stuck with the pre-existing folder types for resources, you cannot add your own. Easiest approach for you is probably going to be just create 2 projects and use one of the sets of resources in each.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way of doing it, but there's always a possibility of creating the copy of a project and changing the resources set. Would like to know if there's any other solution.